# Stop cat from licking wound?

Tags: cats, health, injury, wound-care

About three weeks ago, my senior kitty scraped one of her legs and she started bleeding a bit. After cleaning the wound and applying some topical ointment, it was healing nicely and it stopped bleeding.

The problem is that she started licking it and it's now bleeding again.

What can I apply to the injury so that she stops licking it and reopens the wound?

Comment: I remember my parents-in-law took a sock over their dog's leg, when there was a wound. But not sure, if this would be possible for a cat too. Is your cat more inside, or regularly outside?